# What does `extends to' mean in this context?

Tags: algebraic-topology

In the following statement, I don't understand what `extends to' should mean.

Every continuous map $S^1\to X$ extends to a continuous map  $D^2\to X$.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's an embedding $S^1 \to D^2$ given by considering $S^1$ as the boundary of $D^2$, and extension means there's a continuous map $D^2 \to X$ which restricts to any given continuous map $S^1 \to X$.

Comment: Given three sets $A,B,C$ such that $A \subset B$, and given a function $f : A \to C$, an *extension of $f$ to $B$* is a function $F : B \to C$ such that for all $x \in A$ we have $f(x)=F(x)$. In your example, $A=S^1$, $B=D^2$, $C=X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an inclusion map $\iota:S^1\to D_2$ embedding $S^1$
as the "boundary" of $D^2$. Then the continuous $f:S^1\to X$
extends to the continuous $g:D^2\to X$ if $f=g\circ \iota$.

Answer (score 2):

Call the first map $f$ and the second  $g$.  Then $g|_ {S^1}=f$.